# Is it Possible to use Mono AOT Compiled (Native)c# Executable and C# Dll(CIL) which has unimplemented Mono Methods

Tags: c#, .net, mono, aot

I have a main C# executable that can be compiled using Mono c# compiler, but the EXE uses DLLs which uses P/Invoke and other mono unsupported methods so I cannot compile this DLL to Mono.  Is there any way use these DLLs with Ahead of Time Compiled Mono Executable?

Comment: So you mean if the dll's has unimplemented methods in mono i cannot use it with my aot compiled main executable.Please make it clear.I not an experienced person when it comes to mono and compilers

Comment: If your code requires framework methods that are not implemented or supported on mono then they aren't going to work are they.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to AOT-compile the main executable and still access non-AOT-compiled libraries.

But AOT is not meant to be an obfuscation mechanism, in particular you still need the original main executable, otherwise your program won't run. The only reason you'd want to AOT-compile an executable/library, is to make it a little tiny bit faster in a few very specific scenarios.

If you want to obfuscate, have a look at [mkbundle](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications#Bundles).

Comment: Thanks What you mean by i need Main Executable.My aim is to distribute AOT Compiler Executable+Libraries

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a little vague, because it seems that you're conflating AOT and P/Invoke. AOT won't call and cache the results of a P/Invoke call, in fact, they have nothing to do with each other.

AOT basically generates native code for the ILDASM .NET bytecode. It has nothing to do with P/Invoke calls. P/Invoke is a runtime .NET function that calls the function from the native DLL.

Contrary to your post, Mono fully supports P/Invoke. Your problem isn't with Mono, hence there's nothing that Mono AOT can do to resolve your issue. Your problem is that the library being P/Invoke'd is not supported on the platform you're running your application under Mono on. No one can help you here; you will need to either reimplement the native functions for the new platform or find a managed alternative.

Comment: Mono Migration Analyser-MOMA Says it does not support P/Invoke

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the semicolon love.

Comment: What about unsupported methods?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Please answer to the Question my question is 'Is it Possible to use Mono AOT Compiled c# Executable and C# Dll' and it is not merely concerned with P/Invokes,Mono still has unimplemented methods

Answer (score 0):

Mono supports pinvoke (If it didnt' it would be nearly useless). AOT compiled code can still call pinvoke methods. The problems you will see will come from the unmanaged C libraries that may not be supported on your target platform ( linux? mac? solaris? )

You have three things here:

- [AOT](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT)
- [PInvoke](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries)
- .Net only libraries

The first two are fully explained in the links above, PInvoke is quite core to advanced .Net/Mono programming and is well supported. AOT is used more often in the [Android](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) or [IPhone](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) targets

The final point, where the libraries you have are only available on windows under .Net usually involves core framework methods that Mono does not implement ( what are you trying to call? ) or are wrappers around windows system calls ( often in to kernel32.dll ) that don't exist on linux or other platforms.

You may find also that even if the assemblies you need appear to run on mono that the original author may not have paid attention to things like using portable directory separator characters and that have always assumed a windows platform.

My advice would be to run a new copy of [MoMa](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) on your program and see what it says.

Comment: MOMA says Mono Supports most methods in Main Executable but it does not support some methods in the .net Dll that's why i want them to be in CIL.I want my main application compiled AOT so that the code is Native rather than CIL,which even a kid can decompile.Obfuscation and packing is trivial to experienced hackers

Comment: Then your question is very poorly worded.  If mono doesn't support some method or class, using mkbundle wont help you.